# Hibernate plugins are not available

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, netbeans

I've installed Apache Netbeans 11 on Windows 7
I'm working on Hibernate but this newly installed IDE doesn't provide plugins to download for Hibernate.

How can I add Hibernate platform in Netbeans IDE 11?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can't because the plugin was removed due to licensing restrictions. The NetBeans developers are aware of this issue and are working on it. To keep track on the status the following links might be of interest:

- [mailing list entry](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/b5036b42a6744709a2f81064b514c134f19f295dfd528e18b6649226@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E)
- [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2599)
- [Another Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2716)